# Bootstrap-rubygem vs twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running a Rails 5 application and am looking to implement Bootstrap for the front-end styling. Can't find a general consensus on the difference between these two gems: https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

The first is more popular by downloads, but the second is maintained by the official Bootstrap team. The first also seems to have generators which would be handy, but if someone could explain the differences that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter uses `sass` while the former uses `less`, since rails typically uses scss (sass) I would go with https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem but do keep in mind that uses bootstrap 4.  If you need 3 or less, use https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass